# Ignore periods in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to ignore periods in XSLT

Input :

```
<target>
        <xor type="frt">88.1234/FFT.mr.874325</xor>
<target>
```

Desired output :

```
<getone name="FRT" val="88.1234/FFTmr874325" />
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template name="target">
    <getone name="FRT">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant::xor[@type='frt']"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </getone>
</xsl:template>
```

When I am using the above code I am getting the output as

```
<getone name="FRT" val="88.1234/FFT.mr.874325" />
```

But I want to ignore the periods after `/`.

I am Using XSLT 2.0 version

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a named template for this (as well as in your other question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:template match="target">
    <getone name="FRT">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(xor[@type='frt'], '/')"/>
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(xor[@type='frt'], '/'), '.', '')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </getone>
</xsl:template>
```